# Does WCF always needs my host to have administrator privileges?

Tags: wcf

I'm following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935.aspx) tutorial and seems like to implement WCF in my application it would need to run with administrator privileges.

I want to use remoting **only** to communicate between processes in the same machine. Anyway, everyone seems to recommend WCF even when this is the case. But if this will require my application to run only with administrator privileges then I'd rather find another solution than WCF.

There seem to be a [workaround](http://developers.de/blogs/rolf_nebhuth/archive/2006/08/02/902.aspx) that involves running the command line and using some tool that varies depending on the Windows OS version. Is this the only way? Would I have to tell my users to run the command line and all that stuff or can this be automated, considering that my application runs on XP, Vista and 7?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Administrative privileges are only needed for the [HTTP URL namespace reservations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx).  If you are using [named pipe communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) (which would be the recommended way to go for inter-process communication), then you can run fine as a normal user.

Comment: Yes, just a method of communication between client and server.

Answer (score 3):

It could well be that because you are registering the endpoint information programatically that you need the elevated permissions. WCF does not require them in most circumstances.

> Services such as this one require permission to register HTTP
>   addresses on the machine for listening. Administrator accounts have
>   this permission, but non-administrator accounts must be granted
>   permission for HTTP namespaces