# Does a WCF callback hosted in a WPF app require elevated privileges?

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding, duplex

I've got a WPF desktop application which communicates over NetTcpBinding with a WCF service hosted in a Windows service on a separate server.  For client notifications we're considering building a Duplex WCF service hosted in the same Windows service.  Clients would register with this service on startup, and the service would cache callback proxies and push messages to clients when an event occurs.

This application will be deployed in many different hospital environments, though, including some environments where users are not workstation admins, or where they must access the WPF app through Citrix.  Does anyone know if client callback proxies over net tcp require either elevated Windows permissions (i.e. run as admin) or special code access security permissions?  Since a callback is essentially a mini WCF service inside your client, it's conceivable that Microsoft would want to lock down that ability.  Assume that the client OS is Windows 7 or Windows 8.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Perhaps this has some information that might help - [Admin Priviledges and WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804230/does-wcf-always-needs-my-host-to-have-administrator-privileges)

Comment: Thanks for the link, @MattC. The question and tutorial are talking about the permissions required to host the service itself. I'm looking for the permissions my NetTcpBinding clients are going to need for providing a callback. This does help me to know that my users will need to be admins if I switch to WsDualHttpBinding for callbacks, though (something that's confirmed by other similar questions).

Comment: AFAIK TCP comms work on Windows authentication, so I think that if you can open a port to connect out (which must then send an ACK back) you should be able to open a listening port.

I think the only way to know for sure is to have a another machine or VM that is setup like the deployment machine.

I think this is probably a wise thing to do anyway.